# Matrix $A$ such that $\vec{v},A\vec{v},A^2\vec{v}$ are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix and suppose that $\vec{v}$ is a vector in ${\mathbb R}^n$ such that $\vec{v}$,$A\vec{v}$,$A^2\vec{v}$ are distinct and non-zero. What can be said about $A$ and $\vec{v}$ if
$$
\vec{v},A\vec{v},A^2\vec{v}
$$
are orthogonal to each other? Is $A$ some kind of a rotation matrix?

Comment: $A$ can also be a permutation matrix, exchanging generators of an orthonormal basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say much about the behavior of $A$ outside the span of $\vec{v}$ and $A\vec{v}$. Complete $\vec{v}_1 = \vec{v}$, $\vec{v}_2 = A\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v}_3 = A^2\vec{v}$ to a basis $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, any $n\times n$-matrix of the form $$B = \begin{pmatrix} B_1 & B_2\\ B_3 & B_4\end{pmatrix} \text{ with } B_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\,,\, B_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0\end{pmatrix}_{(n-3)\times 2} \text{ and }B_2\,,B_4 \text{ of appropriate sizes }$$
defines a linear map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(\vec(v)) = A(\vec{v})$ and $f^2(\vec{v}) = A^2\vec{v}$. Take the matrix $C$ that represents $f$ in the canonical basis and you get that $C\vec{v} = A\vec{v}$ and $C^2\vec{v} = A^2\vec{v}$.

Also, since any pairwise orthogonal and linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be completed (after scaling) to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, any instance of your matrix $A$ is obtained from the construction above after some base change.